# system.js es6 modules can't get started

Tags: javascript, systemjs, es6-modules

According to getting started I created a file called main.js:

```
 export class q {
    constructor() {
      this.es6 = 'yay';
    }
  }
```

In my html file got:

```
<script src="system.js"></script>
<script>
  SystemJS.import('main.js')
  .then(null,(err)=>console.error(err))
</script>
```

When loading the page I get:

> Error: Unable to dynamically transpile ES module    A loader plugin
>   needs to be configured via `SystemJS.config({ transpiler:
>   'transpiler-module' })`.   Instantiating http://localhost:8080/main.js
>   Loading main.js
>       at transpile (system.js:3650)
>       at system.js:3433 SystemJS.import.then @ index.html:17

The system.js file I got from here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/systemjs/systemjs/master/dist/system.src.js

Running static content from http-server (node) with cache killer plugin installed in Chrome.

Not sure what this is but I'll continue reading the docs and maybe find the solution. A bit sloppy for it to break at "getting started" though.

**update**

I guess this has something to do with it:

https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/issues/1312

But nothing there about how to make the error go away. Code works in Chrome and will be transpiled by babel, only part I need system.js for during development is to load the module.

**update**

https://youtu.be/5P04OK6KlXA?t=3m3s

Looks like the "getting started" should mention that for the example to work one needs traceur as well.

After some searching I found the traceur.js here: http://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/bin/traceur.js

Changed the html to:

```
<script src="traceur.js"></script>
<script src="system.js"></script>
<script>
  SystemJS.import('./main.js')
  .then(null,(err)=>console.error(err))
</script>
```

And it still the same error.

**update**

Installed systemjs and traceur with npm and added them to the html:

```
<script src="./node_modules/traceur/bin/traceur.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
```

Same error. I'm done with this and revert to requirejs for developing, r.js with uglify for distribution.

Was looking into this after reading something about rollup and how compiled code can be smaller when it only imports what you need instead of the entire file.